# putting a function in class instead of code behind

Tags: asp.net

I have a function in a code behind file that's used to respond to a gridview event:

```
protected void GridviewEval(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
{
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
      foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
      {
       if (cell.Text == "0") { cell.Text = "-"; }
      }
```

}
 }

It's currently in the code behind of a page and I'll be using it in other other pages. I would like to use the same code in other pages. When I cut and paste the function into a class, it's not working.

I'm sure it's simple but I can't figure it out.

Thanks.

Comment: Can you show the code as it sits in your external class?

Comment: Just clarifying: you wire up the event handler for one of the gridview events in the new page, then forward the call to the method you've extracted into the class module?  Seems like that should work.  Is there anything else going on?  Maybe you can post the markup for the gridview, the event handler, and the declaration of the method in your "GridHelper" class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this method can easily be static, so just a static method in a static class and you're homefree.

```
public static class CommonEventHandlers
{
   public static void GridviewEval(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
   {
     if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow)
     {
        foreach (TableCell cell in e.Row.Cells)
        {
           if (cell.Text == "0") { cell.Text = "-"; }
        }
      }
   }    
}
```

and then on the pages where you have your gridview you wire the event up like this

```
myGrid.SomeEvent += new SomeEventHandler(CommonEventHandlers.GridviewEval)
```

Comment: when I put it in a class file, the void keyword is underlined red with the message Expected class, delegate, enum...

Comment: do you remember to put the method inside a class? technically there is no such thing as a class-file. Visual Studio has it in its "New Item"-list, but its just a text-file with the extension .cs that the compiler will compile.

Comment: It's telling me that GridViewRowEventArgs and DataControlRowType are not part of the context, missing directive. I tried adding some "using" clauses but I guess I'm not putting the right ones in place. I'm confused.

Comment: its not easy if you don't even have the fundamentals... http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/sf0df423.aspx *using Directive (C# Reference)* you need a using directive to the namespaces your types are located in.

Answer (score 0):

There are at least two approaches. Either derive your page code behind class from a class you create and move the code there, or alternatively use a proxy mechanism, where you have a separate class, either a singleton or a static class, and have the methods in your page simply act as a proxy to pass the call through to the singleton/static class.